# Why can't I block YouTube with iptables?

Tags: linux, firewall, iptables, youtube

Following [this answer's advice on blocking sites with iptables](https://superuser.com/a/705922/1186851), I have blocked many sites perfectly fine, but for some reason YouTube seems immune and is not blocked. It doesn't matter if I also block `googlevideo.com`, which YouTube depends on; that site is immune too.

The contents of my rules.v4 file:

```
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m string --string "youtube.com" --algo kmp --to 65535 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
COMMIT
```

Comment: This will only work with non-encrypted TLS Server Name Indication. Do we still have that? I'm not entirely up-to-date.

Comment: I'm GUESSING that Google is using the QUIC protocol (ie UDP) which is UDP based and which your rule does not match.

Comment: Does https://askubuntu.com/a/1432900 answer your question?

Comment: @LjmDullaart First I tried pasting in the question's rules verbatim. I got an error "chain YOUTUBE does not exist". When I changed YOUTUBE to REJECT like in the answer I linked, I got "can't use -w with iptables-restore". When I removed -w, it didn't work; YouTube remained unblocked. I then tried blocking YouTube in the hosts file, which *still* didn't work.

Comment: @davidgo You are correct! Fixed!

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out thanks to @davidgo's prompting in the comments. Instead of `-p tcp` (which only covers Transport Control Protocol) in the rule, I have to use `-p all` (which covers all transport layer protocols). The full rule looks like

```
-A OUTPUT -p all -m string --string "youtube.com" --algo kmp --to 65535 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
```